# Python String and variable format validation

Tags: python, string, list, algorithm, validation

I have a list:

```
data = ["data 01", "data 02", "data 03"]
```

I want to check if each element in list contain the string "data", and also add the text after data (e.g 01, 02, 03) to another list. Below is the code I have, but I find it to be inefficient.

```
data_2 = []

for item in data:
    if ("data" in item):
        data_2.append(item.replace("data", "").strip())
```

Is there a way to check

```
if item == "data {}"
```

Where {} is a numerical variable. As a precaution to having an item in data list like ["no data"], where the string "no" gets added by mistake?

Comment: Use `item.startswith('data')`

Comment: There are numerous ways, but I would say that [Python re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a regular expression to test that it matches the whole pattern.

```
import re

for item in data:
    result = re.match(r'data (\d+)$')
    if result:
        data_2.append(result.group(1))
```

`result.group(1)` will contain the number that was captured by `(\d+)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a list comprehension:

```
data = ["data 01", "data 02", "data 03"]
d = [s.split('data ',1)[1] for s in data if 'data' in s and s.split('data ',1)[1].isdigit()]
print(d)
```

Output:

```
['01', '02', '03']
```

Comment: This still doesn't check that there's a number after `data`. Did you miss that part of the question?